# How to unit test React component that depends on visual data

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, logic, enzyme

I am building a responsive category bar that puts all non visible categories inside a dropdown. All those category names have a non fixed width (it depends on the text). I am using Jest & Enzyme for the tests.

Basically what the component needs to do is to calculate all the categories that don't fit in the visible bar, and fill an array in the component state called invisibleCategories to populate the dropdown data.

Which would be the better way to unit test it? Since the logical data and state depends on the visual environment, I am not sure about the proper way to set the tests. Would you mount the component in a fixed width div (ie 1000px), set a list of categories (ie Category 1, Category 2, Long Category 3, Short 4...), know which categories should be visible in that given environment and test it? Or there's a more dynamic pattern to test logic that depends on visual data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if something like that could be done with Jest, hopefully someone else could come along with a solution in Jest, but I think all testing frameworks of that type have limitations with what they can do when it comes to the ui.

You could consider using a different testing framework in addition to Jest that's specifically tailored to testing the UI. I'm fond of [storybook](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook), the idea of it is to create a bunch of test cases for your components. Then you click through your tests, eyeballing them and making sure they all look correct. Its not automated but it is very helpful to quickly make sure none of your components have visually broken.

In your example you would create a "story" like so:

```
storiesOf('CategoryBar', module)
.add('Few items', () => (
  <CategoryBar>
    <Item/> <Item/>
  </Category>
))
.add('To many items', () => (
  <CategoryBar>
    <Item/> <Item/> <Item/> <Item/>
  </CategoryBar>
))
```

Then you will be given two tabs within the storybook application which can be used to quickly make sure everything is working as expected.

Sorry I don't have a method of doing it in Jest.